# How do you use Postgresql's json_to_record with an attribute more than 63 characters long?

Tags: postgresql

I have some JSON stored in a `json` database column on a Postgresql 9.5 database. The JSON comes from an external application and I don't control the structure of it. I need to write a query that *flattens* the JSON.

The simple case works:

```
SELECT * FROM
json_to_record('{"a": "this is a", "b": 25, "c": "this is c"}') as x(a text, b int, c text);
```

```
     a     | b  |     c     
-----------+----+-----------
 this is a | 25 | this is c
```

However, some of the JSON contains keys that are more than 63 characters long. In that case, as far as I can tell, when the record definition is created Postgresql truncates the identifier and consequently it no longer matches the JSON key and therefore the column is always null:

```
SELECT * FROM
json_to_record(
  '{"a": "this is a",
    "b": 25,
    "this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute": "this is c"
   }') as x(a text, b int, this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute text);
```

```
NOTICE:  identifier "this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute" will be truncated to "this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characte"
     a     | b  | this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characte 
-----------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 this is a | 25 |
```

Using the truncated version in the record doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM
json_to_record(
  '{"a": "this is a",
    "b": 25,
    "this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute": "this is c"
   }') as x(a text, b int, this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characte text);
```

```
     a     | b  | this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characte 
-----------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 this is a | 25 |
```

What's the best way to get the data out, without recompiling Postgresql with a larger `NAMEDATALEN`?

The reason for using `json_to_record` is that I have a table with thousands of rows containing a json column and a discriminator column. I want to create a view that looks like a normal table for rows with a specific value in the discriminator column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
SELECT
  id,
  date_created,
  date_modified,
  status,
  uuid,
  r1.*,
FROM
  mytable,
  jsonb_to_record(json_col) as r1(
    "columnA" text,
    "columnB" int,
    ""this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute" text)
WHERE
  parent_fkey = 20
  AND status = 'Published'
```

Comment: probably only by changing all keys - preparing before `json_to_record`

Comment: or maybe some workaround? what are you trying to achieve with `json_to_record`?.

Comment: @VaoTsun I have a table with thousands of rows containing a json column and a discriminator column. I want to create a view that looks like a normal table for rows with a specific value in the discriminator column

Comment: so the problem is that some different keys, truncated to 63 become same? Or you just don't like short name of the column?.. your `create view` should work

Comment: The problem is that because Postgresql truncates the name of the column in the record it doesn't match the key in the json any more and so `jsonb_to_record` returns a null value for that column.

Answer (score 1):

a wheel can be invented here to help walk over - you can "rename" keys on the flight. It will fail if you have several different keys that truncates to same 63 chars, but you know that. Anyway,

**sample:**

```
t=# create table so41(i int,j json);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 5.736 ms
t=# insert into so41 select 1,'{"a": "this is a",
t'#     "b": 25,
t'#     "this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute": "this is c"
t'#    }';
INSERT 0 1
Time: 0.989 ms
t=# insert into so41 select 2,'{"a": "this is a1",
    "b": 27,
    "this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute": "this is c1"
   }';
INSERT 0 1
Time: 4.027 ms
```

**wheel:**

```
t=# with tt as (
  with t as (
    select *,j->json_object_keys(j) val,substr(json_object_keys(j),1,63) k
    from so41
  )
  select concat('{',string_agg(concat('"',k,'":',val),',') over (partition by i), '}')::json,i,j
  from t
)
select i,r1.*
from tt
join json_to_record(concat) as r1(a text, b text, this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute text) on true;
NOTICE:  identifier "this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characters_attribute" will be truncated to "this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characte"
 i |     a      | b  | this_identifier_is_going_to_be_longer_than_sixty_three_characte
---+------------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | this is a  | 25 | this is c
 1 | this is a  | 25 | this is c
 1 | this is a  | 25 | this is c
 2 | this is a1 | 27 | this is c1
 2 | this is a1 | 27 | this is c1
 2 | this is a1 | 27 | this is c1
(6 rows)

Time: 0.574 ms
```